# MobilePush Contact Builder Data model

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, contactbuilder

I have mobilePush enabled for all BU's but some of them have more attributes in the  "MobilePush Demographics" table, plus one is related to "MobilePush Subscriptions" and "MobilePush Tags" entities as well.

The one I'm concerned about has only "MobilePush Demographics" with only 3 fields (Device ID, Contact Key and Application).

I have registered an app properly (APNS and Firebase key) and subscribed few contacts via SDK on the BU with basic data model. Why does the model is not fully auto-generated in all Business Units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a "re-prime" and can only be accomplished currently with a ticket to support

Answer (score 2):

@jclobro I ran this by some of my teammates but without a specific and actionable answer. Please log a support request with your Salesforce rep and someone here should be able to work with you to determine the cause and what can be done.